# For Mysql, How Do I get 100 out of 100\\123456

Tags: mysql

I checked all the string manual but I couldn't find a handy way to handle this.

The substring doesn't provide the start and end position for this case, I try to get index of \ and then use start and end position to extract it. I failed.

Is there any good way to achieve this ?

Comment: show the code you attempted this with. you had the right process. find the first ``\``, then use that for substring extraction. but we're not here to write all of the code for you - show your work, and we'll try to fix that.

Comment: I have to wonder if trying to cast that string as an integer will return 100.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yes, it will.  `SELECT CAST('100\\123456' AS UNSIGNED)`. I don't think I would want to see that in production code though.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh, I agree.  Though, personally, I wouldn't want to see SQL being used to extract substrings from data at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

\Here is an expression which should be easy to generalize for any strings:

```
SELECT LEFT('100\\123456', LOCATE('\\','100\\123456') - 1)
```